# sanic-validation Python AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'raw_args'

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, sanic

I am trying to use request validation package `sanic-validation` in a simple Sanic webserver.

Using sanic 20.3.0, sanic-validation 0.4.4 and Python 3.8.3.

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json
from sanic_validation import validate_args

app = Sanic()

query_schema = {
    'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}
}

@app.route('/query', methods=['GET'])
@validate_args(query_schema)
async def query(request):
    print(request.args)
    name = request.args['name'][0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

However, sending a GET request to the `/query` endpoint results in the following error in the Python terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 971, in handle_request
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/n/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic_validation/decorators.py", line 59, in wrapper
    validation_passed = validator.validate(request.raw_args)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'raw_args'
```

Why is this error occuring, and how can we fix this? Thanks!

Comment: A few releases back (I'd have to check which), request_args was deprecated on favor of other more explicit and clear methods to get the args. Looks like the third party package you are using never was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you use an old version of the [sanic-validation](https://github.com/piotrb5e3/sanic-validation/blob/6b06adff5c67691c0d50daa1dbf2a7bf19a85b27/sanic_validation/decorators.py) repository.
As you can see in your exception:

> line 59, in wrapper
> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'raw_args'

Basically, the error says that it doesn't familiar with the *raw_args* attribute in the request object.
I've checked the code of the decorator in the [sanic-validation](https://github.com/piotrb5e3/sanic-validation/blob/6b06adff5c67691c0d50daa1dbf2a7bf19a85b27/sanic_validation/decorators.py) repository, and it seems that they changed it to *query_args* attribute instead (also in line 59).

So, maybe you should reinstall that package or you can just copy the code from GitHub and post it locally.